# True or false: If $||Tv+v ||=||Tv||+||v||$, then $1$ is eigenvalue of $T$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be an inner product space over $\mathbb{C}$. And let $T:V\to V$ be an unitary transformation. Suppose that for $ 0 \neq v\in V$ we have $||Tv+v ||=||Tv||+||v||$, then $1$ is eigenvalue of  $T$.

My attempt: We need to prove show that $Tv=v$. So, if I "put it" on the equation above, I'll get:

$$||Tv+v ||=||Tv||+||v||$$

$$||v+v ||=||v||+||v||$$

$$2||v||=2||v||$$

So, the the statement is true, right?

Comment: What you have written are just implications and not equivalences. You can't say that $$||v+v ||=||v||+||v||$$ implies that $$||Tv+v ||=||Tv||+||v||$$

Comment: Is the phrase "Suppose that for $0 \ne v \in V$" supposed to mean for all or for some?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In an inner product space over $\mathbb{C}$ (or $\mathbb{R}$), $\|u + v\| = \|u\| + \|v\|$ iff $u = \lambda v$ for some real $\lambda \ge 0$. So you must have $Tv = \lambda v$, for some real $\lambda \ge 0$. As $T$ is unitary, you have $\|v\| = \|Tv\|$. So $\|v\| = \lambda\|v\|$, whence, as $v \not= 0$, you must have $\lambda = 1$, so that $v$ is an eigenvector of $V$ with eigenvalue $1$.

Answer (score 0):

$||Tv+v ||\leq||Tv||+||v||$ is called the triangle inequality. The equality occurs if $\exists \lambda \in \mathbb{R}^+\text{ such that }, Tv = \lambda v$. Then use the fact that $T$ is unitary transformation (an isometry) that will give you that $$||Tv|| = ||v|| = ||\lambda v|| $$ 
As $v\neq0$, we will have that $\lambda=1$

Comment: $\lambda$ has to be real to give $\|\lambda v + v\| = \|\lambda v\| + \|v\|$. E.g., you don't get equality in $\mathbb{C}$ with $v = 1$ and $\lambda = i$.

Comment: **Nonnegative** real, as written in Rob's answer.

Answer (score 0):

If $\lambda$ is a eigenvalue with eingenvector $v$ not zero, we have $\parallel Tv\parallel$=$\lambda \parallel v \parallel$. Being unitary, we have  $\parallel Tv\parallel$=$\parallel v \parallel$ $\Rightarrow$ $\lambda=0$ or $\lambda=1$.

Then, $\parallel Tv+v\parallel$=$ \parallel Tv \parallel + \parallel v \parallel$=$ \lambda \parallel v \parallel + \parallel v \parallel$

But $T$ is unitary $\Rightarrow$ $\parallel Tv+v\parallel$=$ \parallel v \parallel + \parallel v \parallel$

Thus, $ \parallel v \parallel + \parallel v \parallel$=$ \lambda \parallel v \parallel + \parallel v \parallel$  $\Rightarrow$ $ \parallel v \parallel =\lambda \parallel v \parallel$ $\Rightarrow$ $\lambda=1$